# Use of 'Like' and 'Unlike' prepositions

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

I am confused about the usage of the words *like* and *unlike* in sentences.
*Like* and *unlike* make me confused because I see them being used everywhere almost interchangeably, and to make matters worse I even saw commas making difference in meaning.

Which of the following sentences is most correct, and least ambiguous?

1. > Unlike Xbox, Playstation can't play Halo.
2. > Playstation can't play Halo unlike Xbox can.
3. > Playstation can't play Halo, unlike Xbox can.
4. > Like Xbox, Playstation can't play Halo.
5. > Playstation can't play Halo like Xbox can.
6. > Playstation can't play Halo, like Xbox can.
7. > Playstation can't play Halo unlike Xbox.
8. > Playstation can't play Halo, unlike Xbox.
9. > Playstation can't play Halo like Xbox.
10. > Playstation can't play Halo, like Xbox.

In case you don't know what I actually wanted to say in those sentences: I'm trying to say that Playstation can't run the Halo video game and Xbox can run that game. I probably should have tried sentences with no brands but I can't imagine any meaningful sentences at this moment which contains like/unlike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use *like* if you are highlighting something the two have in common. Use *unlike* if you are contrasting them.**

In your case, you are contrasting Xbox and Playstation, so go with your first attempt (I'll ignore the pedant's objection that neither can play Halo):

> 1. Unlike Xbox, Playstation can't play Halo.

If you are concerned about the double negative, turn it around:

> Unlike Playstation, Xbox can play Halo.

Your examples 2 and 3 have an extraneous trailing *can*. The phrase *unlike Xbox* already implies the negation of the prior *can't*.

Examples 5 and 6 are interesting:

> 5. Playstation can't play Halo like Xbox can.
> 6. Playstation can't play Halo, like Xbox can.

Example 6 says that Playstation *cannot* play Halo but Xbox can. However, example 5 implies that Playstation *can* play Halo, just in a different manner to Xbox. Example 5 carries the suggestion that Playstation is inferior in this comparison.

Examples 2, 3 and 7 are ungrammatical, example 8 is of similar construction to example 6, and example 9 is of similar construction to example 5.

Examples 4 and 10 each makes a direct comparison between the two, so they say that both cannot play Halo.

Comment: Which of the sentences are better practices?

Comment: @NajeebTaher Depending on how strongly you want to state P's inadequacies, use either *Unlike P, X can play Halo* (strong) or *X can play Halo, unlike P* (as an aside).